# Self-generating random shapes with Geometry Nodes in 3.0

Tags: modeling, displacement, procedural, geometry-nodes

I’m trying to make some procedural shapes with geometry nodes in Blender 3.0, I’ve started with a cube node with some subdivisions that I’ve distorted with some Voronoi and noise textures at different level of details. Some of these textures are set as 4D vectors so I can manipulate the *W* value to *Seed* out different shapes.

Now I want to randomize the seed value of the textures so that it gives me a different shape everytime I duplicate or instance the object. I thought I could add or multiply or whatever the ID Integer of the mesh to the seed so that each new mesh or instance of a mesh gets shuffled with the *seed* but so far I couldn't find any solution.

Any ideas?

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220721/how-can-i-get-a-new-random-seed-for-every-object-using-the-same-geometry-nodes

Answer (score 8):

You can get a semi-random number by multiplying the relative location by a large number. This is my node setup :

[image]

Comment: Yes!!! I tried to use the Object Info Node before, hoping to find a Random output like in the shader editor's Object Info node, I did not thought at all that I could use the unique location of every instance as a factor to change the seeds. It works! Something tells me that is a workaround though, that I might find some issues down the line.... Anyway the solution fits the problem, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking in the wrong direction, instead of displacing a single object and then scatter it everywhere (which gave me the same displaced object in  any distributed point down the line), the best way to get what I wanted was to first instance an object (a cube with some subdivisions and random scale) on points, and then after realizing instances, displace each object by its normals, so that I could have full control over the displacement of the scattered objects.

Although Benus solution works perfectly in different applications, so I'll keep it in mind, thank you!

Comment: can anyone please share these setups? as blend files so i can study them in a reverse order as i really need to learn this.. thanks ALOT in advance