# Randomize modifier inputs

Tags: modifiers, drivers, random

In this model I'm using a couple instances of the simple deform modifier to non-destructively give it a more naturalistic shape. I'd like to randomize the Angle inputs of these modifiers so that each instance of the model is different. I thought that I might be able to use geonodes to produce random numbers, and then use those to drive the modifiers, but I lack coding proficiency and haven't ever got a grip on drivers. There may also be another way I'm unaware of.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270459/2214

Comment: Unfortunately, this is definitely not possible with *Geometry Nodes*, so I removed the tag. Here you might have to work with *Drivers*.